# Adding domain name in digitalocean droplet

Tags: reactjs, dns, digital-ocean, godaddy-api

I have recently bought a domain from Godaddy. I have done the necessary setups to connect it with digitalocean droplet. I can access the website using the domain. The domain is by default using HTTPS. But inside the web app, I have made HTTP requests(for login, sign up). These network requests aren't being made if I access the website using the domain name. But if I access it by using the IP address of the droplet, those network requests were working. I guess the problem is with the domain. There is no SSL certificate present in the droplet. I am using the Nginx server in the droplet. I have used React to build the website.

I am new to web hosting. Can anybody tell me what's wrong here and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, i think the issue might be in nginx config.
SSL requests that are coming to your droplet over HTTPS should be decrypted somewhere... You can either do it in nginx by using a certificate and modifying your nginx config accordingly, or you can use a digital ocean load balancer in front of your server and configure that load balancer to terminate SSL (you can get a digital ocean managed cert)... In both of these cases, your app will receive un-encrypted traffic.

These links might help:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination

https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/how-to/ssl-termination/